# VBScript wont run - Error "Expected Statement"

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code:

```
Dim todaysDate

todaysDate = Day(Now)

Select Case todaysDate

    Case 1 to 5
        Msgbox("1 to 5")

    Case 23 to 31
        Msgbox("23 to 31")
    End Select
```

When I put it in a VBS file and run it, i get "Expected Statement" for Line 9 Char 10.

If i copy and paste the code into Excel's VBA editor, it runs fine with no errors.

Any ideas why it isnt working in a VBS file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBScript, the [`Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614%28VS.85%29.aspx) statement doesn't allow the `x To y` syntax.  You're only allowed to use a single value or a comma-delimited list of values.  You'll have to use an If/ElseIf statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Select Case TRUE 'this is important, HT to Cheran

    Case todaysDate >= 1 And todaysDate <=5
        Msgbox("1 to 5")

    Case todaysDate >=23 And todaysDate <=31
        Msgbox("23 to 31")

    Case else
        'However you want to handle this
End Select
```

Comment: You would need to make the first line `Select Case True` in order for this to work.  Honestly, though, this isn't too different from If/ElseIf/Else.

Comment: @Cheran I get it now. Thank you.  I'll stick to VBA, thanks :)